# How can I modify a record in a binary file?

Tags: c

Today i want to save data to binary file and then change some values in this file. But unfortunately I couldn't do it right. Maybe i have problem with overwrite value in my file! So i used this code for save data to file -

```
People people;
FILE* outfile;

outfile = fopen("person.dat", "w");
if (outfile == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opened file\n");
    exit(1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    people.price = 1;
    scanf("%s", people.name);

    fwrite(&people, sizeof(struct People), 1, outfile);
}

if (fwrite != 0)
    printf("contents to file written successfully !\n");
else
    printf("error writing file !\n");

fclose(outfile);
```

Also `People` is  a `struct`!

```
struct People {
    int price;
    char name[20];
};
```

And after i saved some information in file i tried to edit it using this code -

```
FILE* infile;
struct People input;

infile = fopen("person.dat", "rb+");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
    exit(1);
}

while (fread(&input, sizeof(struct People), 1, infile))
{
    if (input.price == 1) {
        fprintf(infile, "%d", 25);
    }
}
fclose(infile);
```

So i want to change this values where **price is 1** with 25? But I noticed that nothing changed in the file? Why? Maybe I would be wrong with `fprintf(infile, "%d", 25);`?

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: `if (fwrite != 0)` is not the way to check if the call was successful. You need to assign the result of the function call to a variable, then test that variable. Also, you should do it inside the loop, otherwise you're only checking the last call.

Comment: `fprintf()` is for writing a text file, not for writing binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rewrite the entire structure using `fwrite()`. And before you do that, you have to seek to the beginning of the record that you just read, so you can write over it.

```
while (fread(&input, sizeof(struct People), 1, infile))
{
    if (input.price == 1) {
        fseek(infile, -(int)sizeof(struct People), SEEK_CUR);
        input.price = 25;
        fwrite(&input, sizeof(struct People), 1, infile);
        fflush(infile);
    }
}
```